# How to manage routing when building svelte with vite?

Tags: svelte, vite

I am building a Svelte app that uses svelte-navigator for routing and was created with vite, so my problem is that when vite builds, it only builds the index file and not the routes created by svelte-navigator. How do I add these routes to the build?

I've tried this to no effect

```js
//vite.config.js file
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { svelte } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  optimizeDeps:{
    exclude:['svelte-navigator']
  },
  plugins: [svelte()],
})
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to use vite instead of sveltekit? Otherwise sveltekit manages everything that has to do with routing very well.